# Counter for Value in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database that has a distinct row with a column that within other tables has multiple rows. What I'm looking for is a update query that will be part of a stored procedure.

I'm trying to for every row have a counter of 10 which will repeat(see below for example)

```
Load_Id Counter Description
===========================
C60000220121102134421 1 Text for Counter 1
C60000220121102134421 2 Text for Counter 2
C60000220121102134421 3 Text for Counter 3
C60000220121102134421 4 Text for Counter 4
C60000220121102134421 5 Text for Counter 5
C60000220121102134421 6 Text for Counter 6
C60000220121102134421 7 Text for Counter 7
C60000220121102134421 8 Text for Counter 8
C60000220121102134421 9 Text for Counter 9
C60000220121102134421 10 Text for Counter 10
```

This is what I have so far.

I have a query for the table creation with a counter but I can't seem to get a query that looks at each row on the T_DB_CLIENT_INFO table and adds 10 rows with a counter of 1-10 so that a description can be tied to each value.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.LOAD_ID,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.LOAD_ID) AS COUNTER,
    b.STATUS_DESCRIPTION,                                          
    c.CLNT_NM, c.CLIENT_ID, c.DATABASE_NAME, c.FLAG_FILTERED,
    s.[ROUND]
INTO 
    dbo.[load_id_counts] 
FROM 
    T_DB_CLIENT_INFO c 
JOIN 
    T_ICR_STAGING s ON c.LOAD_ID = s.LOAD_ID
JOIN
    overall_status_description b ON COUNTER = b.COUNTER
```

Comment: Your sample SQL is not valid but in any case use the mod (%) operator to make your row_number reset at 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the % operator would be something like this in your case:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    c.LOAD_ID,
    ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c.LOAD_ID) -1) % 10) + 1 AS COUNTER,
    ...
  INTO dbo.[load_id_counts] 
  FROM T_DB_CLIENT_INFO c 
  ...
```

Just using the % operator would give you numbers from 0, but you want numbering to start at 1, so that's why you add the `-1` and `+1`.

Comment: Thank you mendosi. That did exactly what I needed it to do